# How to detect mouse acceleration in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouse, acceleration

I'm logging the mouse movements in a web app.

I'd like to detect the mouse acceleration on a platform (e.g. Windows). Is it possible to do it from javascript, even just in an approximated way? I could ask the user to check their settings with a questionnaire, but it would be much better to detect it automatically.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tool to analyze mouse movements to try find out a way to detect it in Javascript. More exact than using [e.timeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/timeStamp) can't be done, far better than `setInterval()` that deviates from the real timeStamp.

```js
var mouse = {}, mousePrev = {}, debounce, count = 0, move = 0, store = []

function distance(A, B) {
  var dxAB = B.x - A.x, dyAB = B.y - A.y
  return Math.hypot(dxAB, dyAB) || 0
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {

  //The only way to nearly know the position is e.timeStamp
  const time = parseInt(e.timeStamp - mouse.timePrev)
  mouse.timePrev = e.timeStamp

  //get position
  mouse.x = e.pageX || e.clientX
  mouse.y = e.pageY || e.clientY

  if (!move) { //mouse move starts
    move = 1; count = 0; store = [];
    Object.assign(mousePrev, mouse);
  }
  else if (time && ++count < 100)  {
    //math
    const speed = distance(mouse, mousePrev) / time
    const acceleration = speed / time

    //store 
    store.push(time) // ms
    store.push(acceleration) // px/ms2
    Object.assign(mousePrev, mouse);
  }

  clearTimeout(debounce)
  debounce = setTimeout (
    function () {
      var str = "", acc
      move = 0

      while(acc = 1000*store.pop()) {
        str =  "<div style='background:pink; width:" + (100*Math.log(acc)) + "px; margin: 2px;'> " + parseInt(acc) + " px/s<sup>2</sup> during a " + store.pop() + " ms mousemove" + " </div>" + str
      }

      document.querySelector("#acc").innerHTML = "Acceleration:<br>" + str
    }
  , 200)

}, {passive: true})
```

```html
<pre id="acc">Strike the mouse over here</pre>
```

Actually the true formula for acceleration is `(speed - speedPrev) / time` so you may try out if this code to be modified, may suits your purpose:

```js
var mouse = {}, mousePrev = {}, speedPrev = 0, count = 0, store = [], debounce

function distance(A, B) {
  var dxAB = B.x - A.x, dyAB = B.y - A.y
  return Math.hypot(dxAB, dyAB) || 0
}

document.addEventListener ('mousemove', e => {

  //The only way to nearly know the position is e.timeStamp
  const time = parseInt(e.timeStamp - mouse.timePrev)
  mouse.timePrev = e.timeStamp

  //get position
  mouse.x = e.pageX || e.clientX
  mouse.y = e.pageY || e.clientY

  //calculate acceleration
  if (time && ++count < 100)  {
    const speed = distance(mouse, mousePrev) / time
    const acceleration = (speed - speedPrev) / time
    speedPrev = speed
    store.push(time) // ms
    store.push(acceleration) // px/ms2
  }

  Object.assign(mousePrev, mouse); //shallow copy

  clearTimeout(debounce)
  debounce = setTimeout (
    function () { //mouse pause
      var str = "", acc

      while(store.length) {
        acc = parseInt(1000*store.pop())
        const width = acc? 50*Math.log(Math.abs(acc)): 2
        const align = acc < 0 ? screen.width/3 - width: screen.width/3
        const color = acc < 0? "pink": "lightGreen"
        const pad = acc < 0? "padding-left:" + width + "px;": ""
        str =  "<div style='background:" + color + "; margin:0 0 2px " + align + "px; width:" + width + "px; '><div style='" + pad + "'> " + acc + " px/s<sup>2</sup> during a " + store.pop() + " ms mouse " + (store.length? "move": "pause") + "</div></div>" + str
      }

      document.querySelector("#acc").innerHTML = "Acceleration:<br>" + str
      count = 0; store = []; speedPrev = 0;
    }
  , 100)

}, {passive: true})
```

```html
<pre id="acc">Strike the mouse over here</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check distance the mouse has moved over a set interval of time:

```
var mX:Number = _xmouse;
var mY:Number = _ymouse;

function checkDistance()
{
    clear();
    //trace('new distance: ' + Math.sqrt(Math.pow((mY - _ymouse), 2) + Math.pow((mX - _xmouse), 2)));
    lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
    moveTo(mX, mY);
    lineTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
    mX = _xmouse;
    mY = _ymouse;
}

setInterval(checkDistance, 1000);
```

from http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=332961