# Detect Windows 'Enhance pointer precision' in browser

Tags: javascript, mouse

I was wondering if there's a sneaky way to detect if a user has enabled or disabled the 'Enhance pointer precision' option in Windows' mouse settings.
I guess not directly, but since it's basically mouse acceleration, maybe it's possible in one way or the other? Well... this then becomes a more general 'detect mouse acceleration' feature rather than a 'detect enhance pointer precision', but that's fine.

I found and tried this (coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619348/how-to-detect-mouse-acceleration-in-javascript)):

```
var mX:Number = _xmouse;
var mY:Number = _ymouse;

function checkDistance()
{
    clear();
    //trace('new distance: ' + Math.sqrt(Math.pow((mY - _ymouse), 2) + Math.pow((mX - _xmouse), 2)));
    lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
    moveTo(mX, mY);
    lineTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
    mX = _xmouse;
    mY = _ymouse;
}

setInterval(checkDistance, 1000);
```

... but that didn't get me very far.

All thoughts/reflections are more than welcome!

Comment: You're asking for pretty advanced analysis of data. Start with collecting all data using `mousemove` event. You may want to try to plot the velocity of the movement vector and compare results with and without mouse acceleration. Can you tell why do you need this? I think most people have it on, so one solution is to use this function that approximates the result: `function isMouseAccelerationOn() {return true;}`

Comment: I need it for a webgl game, where the speed of the mouse movement affects the damage you do (you throw stuff using your mouse). When the mouse acceleration option is enabled, the same mouse movement inflicts more damage, so I would like to detect it so I can compensate for it. It also gives a much smoother user experience when disabled, so I ask them to turn it off.

Comment: You need to rethink your game design. Most mouses have a button that changes mouse speed and the top speed is typically pretty insane. You can detect it with a decent amount of analysis, but compensating for it sounds near impossible. You'd need to calculate the exact acceleration factor and remove it from final speed. Good luck with that